# Reflection.Emit create object with parameters

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit

I'm creating a dynamic function to create an object at runtime given an object[] of constructor params.  I keep getting the generic exception 'Operation could destablise the runtime' and I can't see what I've done wrong.

The method works fine if the created object needs no constructor arguments - so the problem must be in the code in the for loop.

The code indexes into the given object[] putting the object onto the stack after which the ctor is called and the object returned.

Any ideas???

```
internal static Func<object[], object> CreateObjectFactoryMethodWithCtorParams(ConstructorInfo ctor, int ctorArgsLength)
    {
        Func<object[], object> factoryMethod = null;
        if (ctor != null)
        {
            var dm = new DynamicMethod(string.Format("_CreationFacotry_{0}", Guid.NewGuid()), typeof(object), new Type[] { typeof(object[])}, true);
            var il = dm.GetILGenerator();
            il.DeclareLocal(typeof(int));
            il.DeclareLocal(typeof(object));

            il.BeginExceptionBlock();

            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0); // [0]
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0); //[nothing]

            for (int i = 0; i < ctorArgsLength; i++)
            {
                EmitInt32(il, i); // [args][index]
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0); // [args][index]
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); //[args]
                EmitInt32(il, i); // [args][index]
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelem_Ref); // [item-in-args-at-index]
            }
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, ctor); //[new-object]
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_1); // nothing

            il.BeginCatchBlock(ExceptionType); // stack is Exception
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0); // stack is Exception, index
            il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, EmitGeneratorType.GetMethod("ThrowFactoryException"), null);
            il.EndExceptionBlock();

            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1); //[new-object]
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            factoryMethod = (Func<object[], object>)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<object[], object>));
        }
        else
        {
            throw new EmitGeneratorException("Cannot create instance factory for a null ctor instance");
        }
        return factoryMethod;
    }

        private static void EmitInt32(ILGenerator il, int value)
        {
            switch (value)
            {
                case -1: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_M1); break;
                case 0: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0); break;
                case 1: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1); break;
                case 2: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_2); break;
                case 3: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_3); break;
                case 4: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_4); break;
                case 5: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_5); break;
                case 6: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_6); break;
                case 7: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_7); break;
                case 8: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_8); break;
                default:
                    if (value >= -128 && value <= 127)
                    {
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S, (sbyte)value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, value);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Calling code

```
    Func<object[], object> factoryFunction = GetFunction(someCtor, new object[] { arg1, arg2});
var obj = factoryFunction(new object[] {new SomeClass, "A String" }); //input ctor args
```

Comment: Where is EmitInt32 defined? Is LLVM involved? And EmitGeneratorType is probably the type being built? In other wors, need more info!

Comment: One recommendation if you're going to work often with IL is to build some helper classes so that you can stub out DynamicMethod with a class that generates a full assembly that can be saved to disk.  You can then run peverify and ildasm on the saved assembly to get much better information on what failed.  I also recommend creating assertion helpers, as the Emit methods are fairly low-level and will happily ignore missing parameters or null values.  One particular thing I'd check out is:  EmitGeneratorType.GetMethod("ThrowFactoryException") -- you might need to specify BindingFlags.Static.

Comment: What does your emitint32 look like?

Comment: EmitInt32 is just a helper method to put an int32 on the stack - i'll update the code - it's actually taken from Dapper Marc!

Comment: Thanks - it looks right, but was worth checking. Darn, I'll have to launch an IDE now,,,

Comment: Dan - thanks for this - I will try this.  The call to the ThrowFactoryMethod works as i can put a break point and it hits it but always with the int param 0, which is why i think something in the loop code it doggy.

Comment: what are the constructor parameters in your actual code? all object? or...

Comment: Marc is it something to do with Ldelem_Ref as both object and value types are put onto the stack?

Comment: @Jon; yes - I've posted the fix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works fine for me, as long as I make all the constructor parameters `object`:

```
class SomeClass {
    public SomeClass(object s, object t) { }
}
static void Main()
{
    var someCtor = typeof(SomeClass).GetConstructors()[0];
    Func<object[], object> factoryFunction = CreateObjectFactoryMethodWithCtorParams(someCtor, someCtor.GetParameters().Length);
    var obj = factoryFunction(new object[] {"A String", 123 });
}
```

I think the problem is that you haven't done any conversions from the objects from the array to the actual constructor types, noting that you need to consider both reference types and value-types (unbox). Like so:

```
var parameters = ctor.GetParameters();
for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length ; i++)
{
    EmitInt32(il, i); // [index]
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0); // [nothing]
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); //[args]
    EmitInt32(il, i); // [args][index]
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelem_Ref); // [item-in-args-at-index]
    var paramType = parameters[i].ParameterType;
    if (paramType != typeof(object))
    {
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, paramType); // same as a cast if ref-type
    }
}
il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, ctor); //[new-object]
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_1); // nothing
```

as a minor note: since you need to call `.GetParameters()`, you should **not** pass in the parameter length as a parameter to the method; that is redundant, and could cause errors when wrong.

This then works with my exmaple:

```
class SomeClass {
    public SomeClass(string s, int t) { }
}
static void Main()
{
    var someCtor = typeof(SomeClass).GetConstructors()[0];
    Func<object[], object> factoryFunction = CreateObjectFactoryMethodWithCtorParams(someCtor);
    var obj = factoryFunction(new object[] {"A String", 123 });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to change the method to do conversion. Thanks for the help though

Comment: @Jon you have **no idea** how many times I've seen "could destabilise the runtime" and "due to an internal limitation" ;p IL is... very fussy.

Comment: I know the feeling - Thanks to Dapper I've been playing with Emit lately and sped our code base up no end.

Comment: @Jon if you want to see truly evil emit, see protobuf-net ;p

Comment: @Marc, The biggest headache I've run into with Emit is when I accidentally miss a parameter on an OpCode that expected one (like the Type token expected for Ldelem).  It proceeds to happily emit bytecode that, when opened in ildasm (or compiled by the runtime), makes no sense--"Wait, I don't remember ever emitting ldarg.2 ..."  Still, I'm glad to have the Emit feature available; it wouldn't be nearly as much fun to write compilers for obscure automation languages if I had to compile them directly to machine code.